# Format elapsed time value string

Tags: csv, vbscript, format, timestamp

I receive a CSV file daily in which I filter to look for certain data. This file requires a lot of manual effort within Excel to filter and format the data.  I am devising a VBScript to look at each line to return only the data needed to reduce the manual effort.

Within the CSV file is a "time seen" string which is formatted strangely. The "time seen" data differs from line to line. An example of this data is the following:

```
3hrs27min 35sec
35min 20sec
8min 38sec
1days1hrs25min 30sec
5days12hrs9min 48sec
```

I am using this code snippet to remove the "days", "hrs", "min ", and "sec" from the data and replace them with a ":".

```
strLastField0 = arrFields(9)
strLastField1 = Replace(strLastField0,"min ",":")
strLastField2 = Replace(strLastField1,"hrs",":")
strLastField3 = Replace(strLastField2,"days",":")
strLastField4 = Replace(strLastField3,"sec","")
```

The result is the following:

```
d:h:m:s
3:27:35
35:20
8:38
1:1:25:30
5:12:9:48
```

I am looking to have the data come out formatted in the following manner instead of what it currently is.

```
 hh:mm:ss
 03:27:35
 00:35:20
 00:08:38
 25:01:25
132:09:48
```

Here is a function in which I have been working with to accomplish this, but my attempts have failed to get the formatting like I want.

```
Function funcFormatTime(TimeString)
    Dim TimeArray
    Dim h, m, s, hh, mm, ss

    TimeArray = Split(TimeString, ":", -1, 1)

    d = TimeArray(0)
    h = TimeArray(1)
    m = TimeArray(2)
    s = TimeArray(3)

    Do Until s < 60
        s = s - 60
        m = m + 1
    Loop

    Do Until m < 60
        m = m - 60
        h = h + 1
    Loop

    Do Until h < 24
        h = h - 24
    Loop

    If Len(Trim(h)) = 1 Then hh = "0" & h Else hh = h
    If Len(Trim(m)) = 1 Then mm = "0" & m Else mm = m
    If Len(Trim(s)) = 1 Then ss = "0" & s Else ss = s

    funcFormatTime = hh & ":" & mm & ":" & ss
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a regular expression to split the input strings using the `.Replace` method with a function pointer that will receive as arguments each of the elements in the string if present or an `Empty` value if not present.

```
Option Explicit

Dim aStrings
    aStrings = Array( _ 
        "3hrs27min 35sec", _ 
        "35min 20sec", _ 
        "8min 38sec", _ 
        "1days1hrs25min 30sec", _ 
        "5days12hrs9min 48sec" _ 
    )

Dim sTime
    For Each sTime in aStrings
        WScript.Echo funcFormatTime( sTime )
    Next 

Function funcFormatTime( inputString )
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "^(?:([0-9]+)days)?(?:([0-9]+)hrs)?(?:([0-9]+)min)?(?:\s*([0-9]+)sec)"
        funcFormatTime = .Replace( inputString, GetRef("funcCalcTime") )
    End With
End Function

Function funcCalcTime( matchedString, d, h, m, s, offset, originalString )
    funcCalcTime =  LeftZeroPad( CLng("0" & d) * 24 + Clng("0" & h), 2) & ":" & _  
                    LeftZeroPad( CLng("0" & m), 2) & ":" & _  
                    LeftZeroPad( CLng("0" & s), 2) 
End Function 

Function LeftZeroPad( value, length )
    LeftZeroPad = CStr(value)
    If Len(LeftZeroPad) < length Then 
        LeftZeroPad = Right(String(length, "0") & CStr(LeftZeroPad), length)
    End If
End Function
```

Each of the elements in the regular expression have the form

```
(?:([0-9]+)days)?
```

Where `(?:   )?` means that the parenthesis do not define a capture group (`?:`) and that this group could or couldn't be present (the closing `?`). Inside this expression there is a `([0-9]+)` that define a capture group that match a sequence of numeric digits. Capture groups are passed as arguments to the replace function, where the only work to do is properly format the values.

Comment: That worked wonderfully! Thank you for helping me out with this.